# How to speedup mkcls step in mgiza++ or giza++, it taking up lots of time for word clustering?

Tags: machine-translation, giza++, smt-language-processing

I am using the MGIZA++ for aligning word from the bitexts from United Nations Parallel Corpus。

Before training the alignment model using MGIZA++, I need to use the `mkcls` script to make classes that is necessary for Hidden Markov Model algorithm as such:

```
mkcls -c50 -n10 -ptest.en -Vtest.en.vcb.classes
```

i'm trying it on corpus with 1,000,000 lines, but is takes a long time and still can't get result (when I try a small dataset, it works).

Is there a multi-threaded or parallel toolkit to do mkcls?

Comment: Yes, `mkcls` is a bane in the ***. Use `clustercat` see  http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N16-1139.pdf and http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W/W16/W16-4618.pdf (Disclaimer: Shameless but necessary plug). https://github.com/jonsafari/clustercat

Comment: thks, it helps. it can use into MGIZA++ or GIZA++ ?

Comment: it's a replacement for `mkcls` so it should work for all versions of giza that uses mkcls

Comment: thks, it very helpful.

Comment: @alvas great thanks.